# Laravel Varbox - get translatable model attribute value in certain language

Tags: laravel, eloquent, translation, multilingual

I'm using the Varbox 2.x paid platform in one of my projects and I have a question regarding translatable models.

I have a `News` custom entity on which I've applied the `HasTranslations` trait in order to support `title` and `content` in multiple languages.
Everything works great and the admin crud also supports multi-language.

Also, in my frontend I've noticed that by accessing `$news->title` (just normal Laravel syntax) returns the value for the locale I'm currently on.

I was wondering if for example I could get the title in English, even if my locale is set to `fr`.

Thanks! Great work creating this package!

Comment: @OMR he's using Varbox, as pointed out in the title of the question

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to get any attribute's value in any of the supported languages, regardless of your set locale, by using the `getTranslation` method.

```php
$news = News::find($id);

$titleInEnglish = $news->getTranslation('title', 'en');
```

Here's the doc section for reference: https://varbox.io/docs/2.x/translatable-models#get-translation

---

Also, regarding what you've said that accessing `$news->title` returns the value for the locale you're currently set to, yes, that's true.

That's done inside the `Varbox\Traits\HasTranslations` trait, namely inside the `getAttribute` method (which actually uses the same `getTranslation` method, but with your set locale by default).

This is done to ease the implementation process, thus keeping it Laravel friendly :)